# Filter only if a condition is valid across time in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to understand how can I use the `filter` function after grouping by ID. I want to filter ID where DV is less than 0.1 at all time >0. Time 0 is the baseline.

Below is the example for my initial data:

[image: Input]

Final expected output

[image: Final output]

Comment: `dplyr::group_by(dat, ID) %>% dplyr::filter(all(TIME < 1 | DV < 0.1))`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: to clarify is it: `dplyr::group_by(dat, ID) %>% dplyr::filter(all(TIME < 1 | DV < 0.1))` or `dplyr::group_by( ID) %>% dplyr::filter(all(TIME > 0 | DV < 0.1))` ? as I want time >0 and DV <0.1

Comment: Have you tried it? Your second logic is backwards. The first logic says *"where DV is less than 0.1 **OR** TIME is 0"*.

Answer (score 1):

Fake data, since I don't have yours.

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  ID   = c(1,1,1,          2,2,2,          3,3,3),
  TIME = c(0:2,            0:2,            0:2),
  DV   = c(100,0.01,0.01,  100,0.05,0.09,  100,0.01,5)
)

dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(all(TIME < 1 | DV < 0.1)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#      ID  TIME     DV
#   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1     1     0 100   
# 2     1     1   0.01
# 3     1     2   0.01
# 4     2     0 100   
# 5     2     1   0.05
# 6     2     2   0.09
```

Comment: so it was an `|`.

Comment: `dat <- data.frame(
  ID   = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  TIME = c(0:6,            0:6,            0:6),
  DV   = c(100,0.01,0.01,0.09,09,0.09,0.09,  100,0.05,0.09,0.09,09,0.09,0.01 , 100,0.01,0.01,5,10,0.09,0.1),
  WT   = c(40,40,40,40,60,40,40,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,100,100,100,100,100,100,100))

`

Comment: So, my goal here is so identity the weight for which the DV is always below 0.1 all the TIME. In this case, for `ID==3` DV is greater than 0.1 at `TIME==3`  hence I can concluded that between 40-60 it is always below 0.1 where as for 100 there is likelihood it might be always below 0.1. Does this help ? How can I implement this condition ?

Comment: Desired output  is  
`dat %>% filter(ID!=3)` So how can I link time and DV to filter subjects for which DV is always below 0.1.

Comment: So, it is basically to check  if a value is below threshold across all the time points  in r and filter subjects only when this condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
THRESHOLD = 0.1
INITIAL_TIME = 0
filter(dat, ((DV < THRESHOLD) | (TIME == INITIAL_TIME)) & 
    (!ID %in% distinct(filter(dat,(DV > THRESHOLD) & 
    (TIME > INITIAL_TIME)) %>% select(ID))))
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.